# Dealing with whitespace in cURL

Tags: curl, ftp, whitespace, libcurl

I'm trying to use cURL to transfer files to an ftp server, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to deal with whitespaces in my directory names.  For example, I try the following code:

```
C:\cURL\curl -T C:\Documents and Settings\outputfolder\temp1.txt ftp://ftpsite.com/ --user username:password
```

but it responds with "curl: Can't open 'C:\Documents'!"  I figured it has any issue with the whitespace, so I tried replacing it with %20:

```
C:\cURL\curl -T C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\outputfolder\temp1.txt ftp://ftpsite.com/ --user username:password
```

but it then responds with 'curl: Can't open 'C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\outputfolder\temp1.txt'!'

So, how do I go about dealing with the whitespace characters when I'm trying to specify the folder and file that I want to transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your filenames in double quotes.

I.e.:

```
C:\cURL\curl -T "C:\Documents and Settings\outputfolder\temp1.txt" ftp://ftpsite.com/ --user username:password
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, that seemed to do the trick!  Although now it's saying that it failed to upload the file (error 552?), but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

`CMD.EXE` doesn't understand `%20`.  Use doublequotes instead:

```
C:\cURL\curl -T "C:\Documents and Settings\outputfolder\temp1.txt" ftp://ftpsite.com/ --user username:password
```

Answer (score 1):

Try '\ ' or putting quotes around the directory name.